# How do I stop console.readLine()?

Tags: java

This is some of my example code:

```
public class test implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {

    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String s = console.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    run();
 }
}
```

My goal is after a few seconds to stop console.readLine().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a timer around the code you want to run for a few seconds. Like so:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code here
        }
    }, 
    5000 
);
```

Comment: This works for what I want it to work for. Though Mike Nakis's answer is good also.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a non-blocking standard input reader so that you never have to worry about things like that anymore:

```
public final class NonblockingStandardInputReaderThread
{
    private NonblockingStandardInputReaderThread()
    {
    }

    public static void start( Consumer<String> lineConsumer )
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( 
            System.in ) );
        Thread backgroundReaderThread = new Thread( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while( !Thread.interrupted() )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        if( line == null )
                            break;
                        lineConsumer.invoke( line );
                    }
                    catch( IOException e )
                    {
                        System.out.println( getClass().getName() + ": " + e );
                    }
                }
            }
        }, NonblockingStandardInputReaderThread.class.getName() );
        backgroundReaderThread.setDaemon( true );
        backgroundReaderThread.start();
    }
}
```

So, for example with this:

```
    NonblockingStandardInputReaderThread.start( s -> System.out.println( s )  );
```

you can have every line of text submitted via the standard input echoed in the standard output without any blocking.